# C++ char array corruption?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, corruption

I'm trying to build a function that compacts the sprintf function, but somehow I ran into the following problem:

The first line after calling the class (It used to be a function, but that didn't work either) I get the correct result: http://puu.sh/1m1Bw

But the line after I get something completely different, while I didn't even touch the class or the variable: http://puu.sh/1m1BR

Can someone explain to me what's happening here?

Edit: Forgot the actual class:

```
StringCreator::StringCreator(char* _parten, ...) {
        char buff[255];

        va_list args;
        va_start (args, _parten);
        vsprintf (buff,_parten, args);
        va_end(args);

        this->str = buff;
    }
```

And in the .h file:

```
class StringCreator {
public:
    StringCreator(char* _parten, ...);
    char* str;
};
```

Comment: No. It's impossible to explain what is happening unless you show us the code...

Comment: You have an error in your code.

Comment: Oow shoot, fotgot the class: 
StringCreator::StringCreator(char* _parten, ...) {
  char buff[255];

  va_list args;
  va_start (args, _parten);
  vsprintf (buff,_parten, args);
  va_end(args);

  this->str = buff;
 }

Comment: @Thijs Edit your question and post that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `StringCreator()` constructor is complete the member variable `this->str` is a dangling pointer as it is pointing to `buff` which is a local variable of the constructor. Accessing `this->str` after the constructor is undefined behaviour. Changing `str` from a `char*` to a `std::string` is a solution and if you need access to a `const char*` you can use `str.c_str()`. Using a `std::string` also means the default copy constructor and assignment operator are correct.

If, as indicated in the comment to this answer, you `new char[255]` instead of using a `std::string`, then you need to either make `StringCreator` non-copyable or implement a copy constructor and assignment operator that copies the content of `str`. See [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) Alternatively, you could have `char str[255];` and avoid dynamic allocation and default copying of `StringCreator` would be correct.

To avoid potential buffer overrun on the call to `vsprintf()` use [`vsnprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) instead (if your compiler supports C99) which accepts as an argument the size of the buffer being populated and does not write more than the specified size.

Comment: Ofcourse! Thank you! Changed it to: `code` StringCreator::StringCreator(char* _parten, ...) {
  str = new char[255];

  va_list args;
  va_start (args, _parten);
  vsprintf (str,_parten, args);
  va_end(args);
 }